# Sub select in Big Query Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can't seem to solve this SQL problem. I have sub select queries and would like to add a where clause:

```
SELECT 

  -- Custom Dimension Canonical URL (Hit)
 (
    SELECT
      value
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
    WHERE
      index = 1
    GROUP BY
      1
  ) AS canonicalURL,

  -- Custom Dimension Publishing Date (Hit)
  (
    SELECT
      value
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
    WHERE
      index = 8
    GROUP BY
      1
  ) AS articlePublishingDate

FROM
  ${constants.ga_tables} AS session,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191103'
  AND FORMAT_DATE(
    '%Y%m%d',
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  )
  AND totals.visits = 1

GROUP BY
  1,
  2
```

In the outer where clause I would like to filter on
    articlePublishingDate is not null
like so:

```
FROM
  ${constants.ga_tables} AS session,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191103'
  AND FORMAT_DATE(
    '%Y%m%d',
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  )
  AND totals.visits = 1 AND articlePublishingDate is not null
```

However, I'm getting an "Unrecognized name" error. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Travis Please refrain from creating duplicate tags. We already have the [tag:google-bigquery] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `AND articlePublishingDate is not null` you can try any of below options

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE index = 8)
```

or

```
AND 8 IN (SELECT index FROM UNNEST(arr))
```

Comment: @Andii - consider also voting up the answer if it helped!